# Command not found when ran with execSync in github Codespace

Tags: javascript, node.js, visual-studio-code, discord, github-codespaces

I am using a github codespace to test a discord.js bot. In it i use the command `fortune | cowsay` which uses the `fortune` and `cowsay` commands, the fortune command is installed with `sudo apt install fortune-mod` and cowsay with `sudo apt install cowsay`. Their install directory is under "/usr/games" and not "/bin" therefore when I run the command `fortune | cowsay` I get

```
bash: fortune: command not found
bash: cowsay: command not found
```

This is because in Github codespaces /usr/games is not in the $PATH

When I added "/usr/games" to the path in both "/etc/profile" and "~/.profile" using
`export PATH="/usr/games:$PATH"`put at the bottom of both the files and then used the command "source /etc/profile" and in later testing "source ~/.profile" The commands work... but it is when I try to run the file using VScode's built in runner (hitting f5 and clicking on node.js) where it automatically makes a new shell and uses node to run the file it commands not found.

I am wondering how GitHub codespaces makes their new shells without the new path I added. And how I might be able to add the `/usr/games` directory to the path for the new shell that opens when vscode runs the file

Answer (score 0):

While the shells that you use within a Github Codespace are interactive, they are not login shells. Only login shells run the `/etc/profile` and `~/.profile` files.

You can test whether a shell is a login shell or not by running the following command:

```
shopt -q login_shell && echo 'login shell' || echo 'not login shell'
```

You can either:

1. Set the `PATH` in a `.bashrc` file or the like; interactive non-login files will run this file. Although I believe it is not best practice to set `PATH` in a file other than `.profile`.
2. Once connected to your Codespace via a terminal, run `bash -l` to start a new shell as a login shell.
3. Create a new terminal profile in the remote `.vscode-remote` `settings.json` file - going to `Settings` and `Remote [Codespaces]`, click the `Edit in settings.json` button should get you here, then add a new profile to `terminal.integrated.profiles.linux`...

```
"terminal.integrated.profiles.linux": {

        "bash (login)": {
            "path": "bash",
            "args": ["-l"],
            "icon": "terminal-bash"
        },
        ...
    }
```

Then in VS Code open a new terminal with the `bash (login)` profile.